# Rasterization of a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, rasterization

I want to have a raster representation of the river, so that I could further analyse combining other raster data. I tried extract the DEM, polygon to raster and resample. But the results are not good enough: missing raster cells in some narrow parts. Is there a way to fix it? I have spatial analyst in Arcgis 10.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could enlarge your river (buffer tool) with half pixel width to make sure that there is always at least one pixel that is covered by more than half of the polygon. The problem is that you might then have more pixels than expected. Therefore you can apply the "**thin**" function afterward to reduce the width to a single pixel.

Comment: Thx! It works! I tried a smaller buffer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a finer resolution or smaller cell size to get a better rasterized polygon. Choosing coarse cell size will not give you the results you want. Just reduce the cell size when you convert polygon to raster.

Comment: I tried reducing the resolution. But all the other datasets are format to the "coarse" resolution.

Comment: What projection are you using?

Comment: I use WGS 1984.